# Scope Issue: Array is not passed into promise resolution

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

EDIT: I found my solution. Angular doesn't seem to push to a regular javascript array, but it performs as expected if it's a $scope.array. Any comments on whether or not this isn't the Angular way are appreciated.

I am using Angular to build a service retrieving scores based on zipcodes, and I'm running into an issue of scope I don't understand.

My API returns a value for each zipCode that's fed to the function, which I'm then attempting to append to an Array.

However, the code below throws an error:

```
cannot call method push() of undefined
```

Which tells me that my scoreArray is not making its way into the scope of the promise resolution.

How can I make this function fruitful and return the array after the for loop completes its run?

```
var $scope.scoreArray = [];
var zipArray = [10031,55325,83832];

function getScores(zipArray,scoreArray){
            for(i=0;i<zipArray.length;i++){
                Scoreboard.getScores(zipArray[i])
                .then(function(score){
                    $scope.scoreArray.push(score);
                })
            }   
            return scoreArray;
        }
```

Comment: $scope doesn't need to be declared, instead using `$scope.scoreArray = []`

Answer (score 3):

array.push() returns the length of the new array. You're overwriting it every time with an int value.